# Does any other professional sport apart from tennis give equal prize money to Men & Women?

Tags: international-sports, awards

Professional tennis, in Grand Slams & certain joint events held on the tour, gives equal prize money to Men & Women.

Does any other professional sport give equal prize money to Men & Women?

Comment: 83 percent of sports give men and women equal prize money now